# Is Hoshea the same as Joshua?

Tags: deuteronomy

In Deuteronomy 32:44 (KJV)

> And Moses came and spake all the words of this song in the ears of the people, he, and Hoshea the son of Nun.

Is Hoshea the same as Joshua?

Comment: Are you asking if the birth name הוֹשֵׁ֥עַ Hoshea had the same meaning as יְהוֹשֻֽׁעַ "Yehoshua" (Joshua)?

Comment: @חִידָה some translations have Joshua others Hoshea and for the English/Portuguese reader the names don't look very similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common "problem" in the ancient Scriptures, but only for moderns who insist upon correct spelling.  The ancients were much less punctilious about spelling.

I leave it as an excercise for the reader that people's names were often spelled differently in the Bible such as Silas vs Silvanus; Joshua vs Oshea vs Hoshea, Jehoram vs Joram, etc, etc.

In this case, the book of Deuteronomy has such a practice.  Thus, Hoshea is the same as Joshua in Deut 32.  Some versions like the NIV standardize the spelling for modern readers.

Answer (score 2):

Is Hoshea the same as Joshua?

Yes.

Numbers 13:16
New International Version

> These are the names of the men Moses sent to explore the land. (Moses gave **Hoshea** son of Nun the name **Joshua**.)

to Hoshea
לְהוֹשֵׁ֥עַ (lə·hō·wō·šê·a‘)
Preposition-l | Noun - proper - masculine singular
Strong's Hebrew 1954: Hoshea -- '**salvation**', the name of several Israelites

{the name} Joshua.
יְהוֹשֻֽׁעַ׃ (yə·hō·wō·šu·a‘)
Noun - proper - masculine singular
Strong's Hebrew 3091: Joshua -- '**the LORD is salvation**', Moses' successor, also the name of a number of Israelites